# how to close all banners in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How do we close or at least prevent running all banners, popups, alerts, dialog boxes, notifications, etc. with a general-purpose code? (I mean it should not be customized for a website).

My code is:

```
def close_banners(driver):
    keywords = ['x', 'accept', 'accept all', 'consent']
    xpath_expression = "//button[" + " or ".join(
        "contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '{}')".format(keyword)
        for keyword in keywords
    ) + "] | //span[" + " or ".join(
        "contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '{}')".format(keyword)
        for keyword in keywords
    ) + "]"
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_expression)
    for element in elements:
        try:
            element.click()
        except:
            continue
```

this code does not work for all websites. Maybe the implementation should be something else.